# Removing the <script> elements of an HTML

Tags: html, css, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby, with the Nokogiri module, and i want to get the content of the body without the script elements.

Nokogiri parse uses XPATH or CSS 3.0. XPATH i really dont understand, and i can't find the CSS selector to achieve my goals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think such selection is possible with XPath.

I'm not that familiar with Ruby or Nokogiri, but based on [answers to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497450/strip-text-from-html-document-using-ruby), you might want to try selecting all script elements from the HTML document and removing them.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(your_html)
doc.xpath("//script").remove
```

Adjust accordingly.