# Regular expression for matching words between <blockquote> & </blockquote>

Tags: ruby, regex

Basically I want to strip the document of words between blockquotes. I'm a regular expression newb and even after using rubular, I'm no closer to the answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an HTML parser and forget regular expressions. Regex is incapable of correctly handling HTML.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(your_html)
doc.xpath("//blockquote").remove
```

From: [Strip text from HTML document using Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497450/strip-text-from-html-document-using-ruby)

There are more examples of how to use Nokogiri and XPath, if you look around.

Answer (score 0):

raw example:

```
/<blockquote>([^<]*)<\/blockquote>/
```

Comment: This fails for `<blockquote>Some <b>bold text</b></blockquote>`. As I said: Regex is *technically incapable* of correctly handling HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Sample string:

<blockquote>Hello world</blockquote>

type the following regex in rubular
<blockquote>(.+?)</blockquote>

or for something more generic:

<.*?>(.+?)</.*?>

hope it helps!

Comment: This fails for `<blockquote>Some <blockquote>quoted text</blockquote> within a quote.</blockquote>`.

Comment: if we are just talking ruby:

resultarray = htmlstring.split(/<.*?>/). 

The split() method will disregard the regex match and the text between the matches is kept. FYI: the scan() method will perform the opposite of this. 

if you're a newb, i suggest to spend some time learning regexs, it's pretty language agnostic and will serve you well.

Comment: If this comment was for me: No, I'm not a "newb" as far as regular expressions go. ;) And `htmlstring.split(/<.*?>/)` fails for `<b title="HTML is > than RegEx">Don't do HTML with RegEx</b>`.